# Enviar correo electrónico con archivo PDF generado en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy buscando enviar un archivo PDF generado de manera automática mediante JavaScript a un correo electrónico asociado.

```
function descargapdf(){
    var pdf= new jsPDF('p','pt','a4')
    pdf.setFont("courier", "time");
    pdf.setFontSize(11);

    var nom=ape=dom=num="____________"
    if(document.getElementById("NombreVendedor").value != ""){
        nom=document.getElementById("NombreVendedor").value
    }
    if(document.getElementById("ApellidoVendedor").value != ""){
        ape=document.getElementById("ApellidoVendedor").value
    }
    if(document.getElementById("DomicilioVendedor").value != ""){
        dom=document.getElementById("DomicilioVendedor").value
    }
    if(document.getElementById("TelefonoVendedor").value != ""){
        num = document.getElementById("TelefonoVendedor").value
    }
    pdf.text(40,40,"Quien suscribe " + ape +", "+ nom + ", con domicilio en " + dom + ", Celular N° " + num +" \n")  //El codigo sigue en este punto

    pdf.save('Comprobante.pdf')
}
```

lo que necesito es enviar el archivo que se genera en la ultima linea como "***Comprobante.pdf***" a un correo destinado para este fin. Gracias

Comment: El PDF se genera en el navegador, debes subirlo al servidor para poder enviarlo por correo. O podrías usar [smptjs](https://www.smtpjs.com/)

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, ¿Encontraste alguna solución?

Comment: @rodrigoarturo la unica solucion que encontré fue pasarme a php... aunque la otra opcion era enviar solo los datos importantes respecto al pdf hacia el correo, pero no en todos los casos se podria.